# Should I put a threading class in or out of a class method

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, subclass

I am creating a class, several methods of which use threading.

To use threading I often create a sub class of threading. Thread which I should create at top level like this:

```
class mainclass(object):

    def __init__(self, ):
        pass

    def method_a(self, ):
        print('method_a start')
        tlist = list(range(10))
        ps = [subthread(tlist) for i in range(4)]
        for p in ps:
            p.start()
        for p in ps:
            p.join()
        print('method_a finish', tlist)


class subthread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, alist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.alist = alist

    def run(self, ):
        while self.alist:
            t = self.alist.pop(0)
            print(self.getName(), t)
            sleep(1)
```

Or into the method using it like this:

```
class mainclass(object):

    def __init__(self, ):
        pass

    def method_a(self, ):
        class subthread(threading.Thread):

            def __init__(self, alist):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.alist = alist

            def run(self, ):
                while self.alist:
                    t = self.alist.pop(0)
                    print(self.getName(), t)
                    sleep(1)

        print('method_a start')
        tlist = list(range(10))
        ps = [subthread(tlist) for i in range(4)]
        for p in ps:
            p.start()
        for p in ps:
            p.join()
        print('method_a finish', tlist)
```

As I know, if I use the second, the class method may be very long, 
and it seems that *jedi.vim* cannot work well.

If I use the first, for every class-method I have to create a top level class with a different name I only use in one place.

So which should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to create a class. If all it does is run a method, you can pass the method directly to the Thread class through the target parameter:

```
class Main(object):

    def run(self, alist, thread_id):
        while alist:
            t = alist.pop(0)
            print(thread_id, t)
            sleep(1)

    def method_a(self):
        print('method_a start')
        tlist = list(range(10))
        ps = [Thread(target=self.run, args=(tlist, i)) for i in range(4)]
        for p in ps:
            p.start()
        for p in ps:
            p.join()
        print('method_a finish')
```